# Swift 3 remove line underneath navbar

Tags: swift, swift3, uinavigationbar

When my project was in Swift 2, I had this code that worked:

```
extension UINavigationController {
func hairLine(hide: Bool) {
    //hides hairline at the bottom of the navigationbar

    for subview in self.navigationBar.subviews {
        if subview.isKind(of: UIImageView.self) {
            for hairline in subview.subviews {
                if hairline.isKind(of: UIImageView.self) && hairline.bounds.height <= 1.0 {
                    hairline.isHidden = hide
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

But now something changed and it doesn't work. Not sure if it because of Swift 3, or iOS10, or that I'm now testing with a 7plus vs a 6s, but it no longer works. I would call in it viewWillAppear of the view controller that is being shown. I saw an answer on here saying to use

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
```

but that hasn't worked. I tried replacing the content of my old hairLine() with those 2 lines, tried putting them directly in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear but still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")
```

Answer (score 2):

## Before:

[image]

## After:

[image]

## Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Hello World"
    
    let navbarColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: (247/255), green: (247/255), blue: (247/255), alpha: 1)
    let image = UIImage()
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = image
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = navbarColor
    
    let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    let statusBarWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    
    let statusBarView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: statusBarWidth, height: statusBarHeight))
    statusBarView.backgroundColor = navbarColor
      
    view.addSubview(statusBarView)
  }
```

Comment: This breaks some stuff. The Status Bar turns white instead of the color of the navbar. I have a toolbar right below the navbar, and even tho they are set to the same exact color there is now a slight difference in the color between the navbar and toolbar. But to your credit it did remove the line lol

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(_:UIImage(),
        for: .any,
        barMetrics: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

in `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(_:
    nil,
    for: .any,
    barMetrics: .default)

UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = nil
```

Comment: tried this in viewDidAppear & Load but still have the line. Where do you call this code? I'm calling it from a controller embedded in a navbar, as I did with my old code. Should I be trying somewhere else?

Comment: I have it in the viewDidLoad of the controller embedded in a navbar. Let me think about what the issue might be.